# Tkinter auto scroll

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm making a kind of chatroom with Tkinter. whenever you receive a new message it adds the message to a listbox. What I'm wondering is how I can make it so that when you get a new message it auto scrolls to the message?

Comment: The Listbox widget has a `.see()` method that takes the index of an item to be scrolled into view - use `0` or `'end'`, depending on which way your messages are scrolling.  Call this every time you add a message to the list.

Comment: whenever i add something i do it like this ''msg = sock.recv(1024).decode('utf8')
            msg_list.insert(tk.END, msg)" what exactaly do you mean?

Comment: Follow that with `msg_list.see(tk.END)`.

Comment: thanks, I will definitely try it!

Comment: I added it to my code and it totally worked! thanks so much for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a discussion with @jasonharper and he told me to put `msg_list.see(tk.END)` which worked fine.
my code now:

```
msg = sock.recv(1024).decode('utf8') # recives the message
msg_list.insert(tk.END, msg) # adds the message to the list box
msg_list.see(tk.END) # auto scrolls to the bottom of the list
```